# How to have multiple cache versions of ASP.Net Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Is there any way to have multiple cache pages when i am using custom caching (VarByCustom)?

For an instance if i implement a caching custom variable browser vise , i would implement function in global as below

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom == Request.Browser.Version)
    {
         return Request.Browser.Version;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }

}
```

Inside controller

```
[PartialCaching(500000)]
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CachePolicy.Duration = new TimeSpan(0,5,0);
        this.CachePolicy.Cached = true;
        this.CachePolicy.SetVaryByCustom(Request.Browser.Version);

        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

}
```

In this case I want to have multiple cache page on following scenario ;

1. Open page on Firefox ~ Page is cached and return to the browser
2. Open same page on same Firefox browser ~ cached page is sent as response
3. Open same page on Chrome ~ Page is cached and return to the browser since browser is different.
4. Open same page on Chrome browser ~ cached page is sent as response
5. Open same page on Firefox again ~ Since page is cached for Chrome, this will identify as a change and it will cache again for Firefox, but in this case i want have cached page for Firefox in step one instead of caching again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i found

In controller i merge controller name with browser by seperating by a ;

```
[PartialCaching(1000)]
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CachePolicy.Duration = new TimeSpan(0,5,0);
        this.CachePolicy.Cached = true;
        this.CachePolicy.SetVaryByCustom("browser"+";"+this.ID);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

}
```

In global file,  user control name and browser string is split

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    string[] array              = custom.Split(';');
    string controllerName       = array[1];

    if (array[0] == "browser")
    {



        return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0]+controllerName;

    }
    else
    {
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect here at Point 5.

As per the way `VarByCustom="Browser"` works, There is a seperate cached versions of the same page for different browsers. What this means is that for the first time  when a page is cached for Chrome, it doesn't destroys the cached version of Firefox OR any other browsers ( if they exists ).

So, when users make requests from Chrome, a separate cached copy is created for Chrome browser ( only if it doesn't exists already )  and the Cached version for Firefox will still be there .

At any next moment, requests come from Firefox, the cached version of Firefox browser is sent as response.

**NOTE::** using `VarByCustom="Browser"` by default, also considers the Major Version of the browser you are using.

Comment: I am sorry in earlier post i have included wrong code piece, here i am not using Browser, instead i am having my own variable. It can be browser language or version. In that case it happens like above steps